# convert just specific HTML table columns to PDF using jsPDF && jsPDF AutoTable

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to figure out how to convert just specific columns into PDF file. In this time I'm able to print just all the columns of the table but I don't need all of them.

This is how I ipmlemented conversion:

```
function demoPDF() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4');
  var res = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("tableToConvert"));
  pdf.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
    startY: 60,
    tableWidth: 'auto',
    columnWidth: 'auto',
    styles: {
      overflow: 'linebreak'
    }
  });

  pdf.save("pdfExample.pdf");
};
```

Don't you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for bold text.

Refer from https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

> `autoTableHtmlToJson(tableElem, includeHiddenElements)` Use it to
>   generate the javascript objects required for this library from an html
>   table (see from html example). If **`includeHiddenElements`** is set to `true`
>   hidden rows and columns will be included otherwise excluded.

So, for your case, you need to change the code like below:

```
var res = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("tableToConvert"), false);
```

Comment: Great answer. Another way would be to remove specific columns from the `res.columns` variable.

Comment: @PetrBečka : Glad to help you dude :)

Comment: @SimonBengtsson: Yeah u're right dude. We can parse the res.column DOM beofre calling it using `autoTable` method.